# Evaluate if item is already in Array

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to evaluate if an item is already in `existingArr` so that I don't add it multiple times.

But I keep getting an error "Cannot convert value of type String to expected argument type @noescape (AnyObject) throws -> Bool" when I try to evaluate if the `existingArr` already contains an item, on this line `if existingArr.contains(nD.dayOfTheWeek) == false` in:

```
for days in results! {
    let nD = DayClass()
    nD.dayOfTheWeek = days[“D”] as! String
        //check if there is already an existing Day array in prefs
        if var existingArr = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("D") {
            //if so append the new value to that array and store it
            if existingArr.contains(nD.dayOfTheWeek) == false {
                let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
                defaults.setObject(existingArr, forKey: "D")
                defaults.synchronize()
            }
        } else {
            //create a new array and store it
            let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
            defaults.setObject([nD.dayOfTheWeek], forKey: "D")
            defaults.synchronize()
        }
    }
```

I have a general idea of what it is trying to tell me, but not enough to actually figure it out.  Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: You probably need to ``registerDefaults`` for the user default to ensure the object for "D" is an array before retrieving it.

Comment: He does that with `if var existingArr = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("D")`, though it looks like he should be checking if `days[“D”]` exists before casting to `String`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue here is that `arrayForKey:` returns `[AnyObject]?`, and not all objects are `Equatable`.

Why is `Equatable` necessary? There are two implementations for `contains`: one that takes an object, and one that takes a predicate (in the form of a closure). However, the `contains` that takes an object requires the generator (the array in this case) to have elements (the objects in the array) to conform to `Equatable`.

Because not all objects are Equatable, and `existingArr` is of type `[AnyObject]?`, Xcode assumes you are trying to call the predicate form of `contains`. However, `nD.dayOfTheWeek` is not a closure, so Xcode throws an error saying that it isn't a closure.

To fix this, you need to cast the `existingArr` to type `[String]`, because that's what type it is and strings are Equatable:

```
if var existingArr = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("D") as? [String] {
```

Note: This shouldn't actually work because `String` is actually a structure (not an object), but for some reason it still works in a simple playground test. If someone could explain why in the comments, that would be great.

Comment: Thats for the extended explanation, it is very helpful.  But for some reason when I update my code per the line of code, it is still adding items that I already have.  I'm not sure why thats happening still.

Comment: @victorpulak What do you mean it's still adding items you already have?

Comment: Sorry I should have been clearer: the error goes away, but my code is still adding the items to the array multiple times.  So if I run the app, and I add 7 days of the week into the array, then stop the add and run it again, there are 14 days of the week in the array, of which each item is in there twice (Monday is in there twice).  So somehow my `contains` code must not be filtering out the second "Monday", etc.  I hope that makes more sense.